# Angular 7 filter items selected from the store

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

in my component i`ve subscribed from the store:

```
 @Select(AccountsState.getAccounts) items$: Observable<any>;
```

and i use them with ngFor in the html but now, i have an input and i have to filter them. I tried to filter them where i change my filter value with

```
this.items$.pipe(
  filter(item = item.m = filterValue)
)
```

but doesn`t work. Could you give me any suggestions

Comment: Your `filterValue` probably doesn't trigger reemitting the list from `this.items$`. So you could probably turn `filterValue` to Subject and then use `combineLatest`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.items$.pipe(filter(item => item.m === filterValue)`? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: and most likely `this.items$.pipe(map(items => items.filter(item.m === filterValue)))`

Comment: @Kos i think its close to success because i receive an array as next value and i cannot iterate it. This doesn`t work but i will investigate it.

Comment: @Nick1R11, well, you'll still have to resolve the issue @martin mentioned. use [`combineLatest`](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/combineLatest/) to merge latest `items$` and your `filterValueChanges$` _(e.g. see reactive forms valueChanges)_ . **So in the end** you'll have something like `filtered$ = combineLatest(items$, filterValue$, (items, filterValue) => items.filter(item.m == filterValue))`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below...

```
this.items$.pipe(
  filter(item => item.m === filterValue)
)
```